# Testing akka actors with Kotlin and akka-testkit

Tags: akka, kotlin, akka-testkit

I am trying to play around with akka and kotlin. I am using the akka java API. The Actor class works fine. But am unable to implement the testcase with Akka-testkit.

This is my testcase,

```
fun testWordCount() {
    object : JavaTestKit(system) {
        init {
            val masterActor = system.actorOf(Props.create(WordCountActor.WordCountMaster::class.java), "master")
            masterActor.tell(WordCountActor.StartCounting("src/main/resources/", 5), testActor)
            val wcs = expectMsgClass(JavaTestKit.duration("5 seconds"), WordCountActor.WordCountSuccess::class.java)
            object : JavaTestKit.Within(JavaTestKit.duration("5 seconds")) {
                override fun run() {
                    Assert.assertEquals(20, wcs.result.size)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the below error -

```
Error:(39, 17) Kotlin: [Internal Error] org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Error generating constructors of class null with kind IMPLEMENTATION
Cause: Error generating constructors of class null with kind IMPLEMENTATION
File being compiled and position: (39,17) in /Users/kunalkanojia/Workspace/fun/kotlin_word_count/src/test/kotlin/WordCountActorTest.kt
PsiElement: object : JavaTestKit.Within(JavaTestKit.duration("20 seconds")) {
                override fun run() {
                    Assert.assertEquals(20, wcs.result.size.toLong())
                }
            }
```

I am new to Kotlin, what could be the problem?

Comment: How is the code supposed to look in Scala/Java ?

Comment: Which version of Kotlin are you using? The following code ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kxSD8ZBY)) compiles just fine with Kotlin compiler version 1.1.0-dev-2222

Comment: Am using version 1.0.3. The code compiles fine, but throws an error when I run it. And it looks like this in java - https://gist.github.com/kunalkanojia/8202d0690208949054eee8b88cec8da2

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36525910/kotlin-type-inference-compile-error-when-using-akka-java-api?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in kotlin compiler and it was fixed in 1.0.4 branch, fix avaliable within snapshot versions. 
For kotlin 1.0.3 you can use workaround from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11833